# How is my book cover perceived?

Tags: book

I am aware of sites which offer the option to upload a cover so that it can be rated across a number of categories; the problem with this is that these sites appear amateurish (at least in my opinion) and seem to have relatively low traffic, with some sections of the sites not functioning at all.

What I want to know is whether there is another method of finding out how my book cover is perceived.

Or, failing that, a service that people have tried and tested which and which they would recommend.

Answer (score 4):

The process to receive meaningful feedback is always the same:

- network
- evaluate the people in your network
- ask those that qualify for feedback

That is, you have to find people who are both interested in helping you and whom you think capable of assessing your work.

This is not a free service. You have to invest the time to make friends among readers, authors, and graphic designers. If you try to get feedback from anonymous strangers, their help will be unreliable and of unknown credibility.

---

Sample your audience.

1. Create an online questionnaire that asks to evaluate your cover.
2. Post paid advertising on Facebook or elsewhere. Target that advertising to your target audience. Offer some incentive for participaton in a short survey. Clicks on your ad lead to your questionnaire.
3. Collect answers from a large number of participants.

Paying a professional graphic designer may be cheaper.